# How to "instantiate" an abstract class in the superclass?

Tags: scala, inheritance, abstract-class, companion-object

I am implementing an extension of ml.Transformer in Spark; but this question is Scala specific. Here is an example object (part of a Class/Object pair):

```
abstract class UDFTransformer(func: UserDefinedFunction,
                     inputFieldNames: Seq[String],
                     outputFieldName: String) extends Transformer with MLWritable with Serializable {
  ... definitions here ...
}

object UDFTransformer extends MLReadable[UDFTransformer] {

  // Since there are no parameters associted with the UDF, there is nothing to save!
  class Writer(instance: UDFTransformer) extends MLWriter {
    override protected def saveImpl(path: String): Unit = {}
  }
  abstract protected class Reader extends MLReader[UDFTransformer]

  override def read: MLReader[UDFTransformer] = new Reader

  override def load(path: String): UDFTransformer = super.load(path)

}
```

The `new Reader` does not compile because the class is abstract and cannot be instantiated. But; any child class will have to define it; along with its necessary members. I cannot just make `read` abstract as well, this gives me a warning `Only classes can have declared but undefined methods.`

The fundamental problem is that each child class of my UDFTransformer is going to wrap a specific UDF. Therefore, the reader needs to be able to generate a specific UDF object; this can't be declared in the superclass. But this 'factory' belongs in the companion object, not in the abstract class itself.

How can I go about building a companion object for an abstract class that can leave the definition of `read` undefined?

Comment: `def read(transformer: UDFTransformer) = transformer.reader`

Comment: `read` with no parameters is abstract in the superclass `MLReadable`. So I have to implement it as is.

Comment: `def read = instance.reader`

Comment: @kingledion add a parameter

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon `instance` is in scope within the class `Writer` but not in the object `UDFTransformer`

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to do it is by creating an abstract class or trait for the companion objects. Something like

```
abstract class UDFTransformerCompanion[T <: UDFTransformer] extends MLReadable[T] {

  abstract def read: MLReader[T]

  override def load(path: String): T = super.load(path)

}

class SomeTransformer extends UDFTransformer { ... }

object SomeTransformer extends UDFTransformerCompanion[SomeTransformer] { 
  override def read: MLReader[SomeTransformer] = ...
}
```

Not sure why you have the `load = super.load` override, and it doesn't look like you can have a companion object for the `UDFTransformer` itself, at least not one extending this abstract class.

See [`GenericTraversableTemplate`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/GenericTraversableTemplate.html) for a standard library example.